# how to keep width small but img fit the div-container

Tags: css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Snxk.jpg

So I have two image in my html where one on the top and one on the bottom
they are larger than that, but I decreased width however I want the picture to be fit the whole container without increasing width which will stay same size but stretching it from left and right!?

sorry again i'm very new to html and css and thank you a lot

```
<div class="Top-Containers">

    <div class="purpleimg-container">
      <img class="purple1" src="images/purple2.png" alt="mountain-img">
    </div>
    <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud-2.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <h1>I'm Sami</h1>
    <h2>a <span class="web">web</span> designer</h2>
    <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud-2.png" alt="cloud-img">

    <div class="purpleimg-container">
      <img class="purple2" src="images/purple.png" alt="mountain-img">
    </div>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Serif', serif;
  background: #eaafc8;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #eaafc8, #654ea3);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eaafc8, #654ea3);
  min-height: 100vh
}
```

```
.Top-Containers {
  background-color: ##a735b1;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0px;
  bottom: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  object-fit: /fill;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.purple1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}

.purple2 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
}
```

I did even try the Objective-fit and as well didn't work

Comment: Please provide html code and consider also providing snippet code

Comment: Post the HTML part.

Comment: Post the full code please, also you don't need to separate all the classes into different code blocks

Comment: Hello, could you try setting the property `img{ 'width': 100%;}`

Comment: thank you so much again guys,, and appreciate every advice and help, as i'm still very fresh new into this and just made my first website, stuck in that part, i have update it and added the HTML part, hope that makes it clear more

Comment: YT_Xaos i tried however since they are two different picture not one, i have to do positioning separately, however since i'm still new may be there is a way i will still figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Try using the images as div background.

```
.purple1, .purple2 {
  background: url('url-image.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.purple2 {
  background-image('another-image.jpg');
}
```